# How to solve setup.py error during install dlib in Python

Tags: python, windows, setup.py, dlib, python-packaging

How could i solve this error i tried many ways to instal cmake installed succesfully but the dlib getting error everytime to install

> c++ and visiual studio also installed

```
C:\Users\Admin>pip install dlib
```

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/dlib/
Collecting dlib
Using cached dlib-19.24.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dlib
Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [8 lines of output]
running install
running build
running build_py
package init file 'tools\python\dlib_*init*_.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext

```
  ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

C:\Users\Admin>install wheel
'install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you tried installing [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) before running `pip install dlib`?

Comment: i installed cmake and also added the path it says setup.py not ready

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we need to manage the Windows PATH environment for CMake.

For checking whether the PATH has already been added or not, you can go to Environment Variables on Windows by going to This PC > Properties > Advance system settings. Then, go to Tab Advanced and click on Environment Variables.

And then click Edit, if there is no CMake path. You must make a new one.

For a more detailed answer refer: [Installing Cmake in Windows](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10-57348ba1117f)

Thanks.